# Unity - is there a way to show the popup in my game only once per game session?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

[EDIT] Everything is working now! Thank's to @MrMoonMan!

As the title says, I'm working on a mobile game and I just implemented a Check Update popup.

The thing is, the popup is displayed every time the menu scene is loaded, and this is very annoying because if the player goes to the weapon menu and then comes back to the main menu 10 times, he will see the popup 10 times. The goal is to have the popup appear only once per game session, Here is what I tried for the moment but without success:

- Using a bool variable
- Destroy the gameobject to which the checkupdate script is attached when the user presses the "No Thank's" button

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class CheckUpdate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string versionUrl = "";
    public string currentVersion;
    private string latestVersion;
    public GameObject newVersionAvailable;
    private static bool hasBeenChecked = false;

    void OnAwake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        StartCoroutine(LoadTxtData(versionUrl));
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadTxtData(string url)
    {
        UnityWebRequest loaded = new UnityWebRequest(url);
        loaded.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return loaded.SendWebRequest();

        latestVersion = loaded.downloadHandler.text;
        CheckVersion();
    }

    private void CheckVersion()
    {
        Debug.Log("currentVersion = " + currentVersion);
        Debug.Log("latestVersion = " + latestVersion);

        Version versionDevice = new Version(currentVersion);
        Version versionServer = new Version(latestVersion);
        int result = versionDevice.CompareTo(versionServer);

        if ((latestVersion != "") && (result < 0))
        {
            newVersionAvailable.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (GetChecked())
            return;
    }

    public void ClosePopUp(GameObject obj)
    {
        obj.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(this);
    }

    public void OpenURL(string url)
    {
        Application.OpenURL(url);
    }

    public static bool GetChecked()
    {
        if (hasBeenChecked)
        {
            return hasBeenChecked;
        }

        hasBeenChecked = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Destroying the gameobject didn't work? Please attach the code which pops up the menu

Comment: Hi @GeekyQuentin and thank you for your help. I just updated my question with the code.

Comment: setActive.....it doesn't disappear, it hides. This will also make it easier for you to display it again.Or you just destroy it. Although it is a window, the premise is a game body.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Ok so you mentioned that it still happens every time the scene is reloaded. That is because the object is created when the scene is loaded. It isn't saved between scenes.  To handle that properly you need to tell it to not get destroyed when the scene is unloaded and to do that is simple, and that is by Adding DontDestroyOnAwake. Here is an example of the code:

```
public class CheckUpdate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string versionUrl = "";
    public string currentVersion;
    private string latestVersion;
    public GameObject newVersionAvailable;

    void OnAwake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }

    void OnStart() 
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadTxtData(versionUrl));
    }
    
    private IEnumerator LoadTxtData(string url)
    {
        UnityWebRequest loaded = new UnityWebRequest(url);
        loaded.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return loaded.SendWebRequest();
        latestVersion = loaded.downloadHandler.text;
    }

    private void CheckVersion()
    {           
        Debug.Log("currentVersion = " + currentVersion);
        Debug.Log("latestVersion = " + latestVersion);

        Version versionDevice = new Version(currentVersion);
        Version versionServer = new Version(latestVersion);
        int result = versionDevice.CompareTo(versionServer);

        if ((latestVersion != "") && (result < 0))
        {
            newVersionAvailable.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void ClosePopUp(GameObject obj)
    {
        obj.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void OpenURL(string url)
    {
        Application.OpenURL(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good evening @MrMoonMan and thank you for your help.
I tried your method and unfortunately it still doesn't work.. The popup is still displayed every time the scene is loaded again.

Comment: @WhiteRose `The popup is still displayed every time the scene is loaded again...`, oh, well did you remember to add `void OnAwake(){ DontDestroyOnLoad(this);}` to your code?

Comment: No i don't have either OnAwake() or DontDestroyOnLoad(this), should i put that in the same script ?

Comment: @WhiteRose yes I made an edit to my post explaining why it is needed. You can put the DontDestroyOnLoad in your Start function as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm going to try that right away.

Comment: All right, so I made the changes, except now the Popup doesn't show up at all xD

Comment: I just edited my question with the updated code, maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: you are a Genius! Thank you so much, everything is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

,,Menu scene''? It sound some suspicious. If you load and unload whole new scene as menu, state as bool field in MonoBehaviours or modifing the scene structure (destory, create object) will not work beacuse allways will be loaded new scene from scratch. ;)

If you have to have menu on seperated scene use someting other to manage the state. For example:
[DontDestoryOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) objects.
Or some C# static class or singleton (not a MonoBehaviour).

Comment: I'm hopefully it's understandable and it's a correct guess

Comment: I misspoke, in the game there are only 2 scenes (menu and game scene) and the popup is displayed in the menu scene. But in the menu there is a transition between the main menu and the weapons menu (but both are in the same scene called Menu)

Comment: So it will work, beacuse Start() with start coroutine should run only one per scene load

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's not working.. Because the object appears again after the scene is loaded, so destroying the object is not the way i guess

Comment: I would still put the `StartCoroutine(LoadTxtData(versionUrl));` in the OnStart function isntead of OnAwake. Also the `if (GetCheck())` should be at the start of the function not the end.